# Slide div Move Left to right, right to left and after it is in center using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slide

I created the div with class of font-style within this contain message. for example:

```
<div class="font-style" style=position:relative>
Hi all How are you !!!
</div>
```

And the Jquery is

```
   jQuery('.font-style').css({'right': '0px', 'left': '300px'}).animate({
                                    'right': '300px'
                                });
                                jQuery('.font-style').css({'right': '300px', 'left': '0px'}).animate({
                                    'left': '300px'
                                });
```

On Load it appear center and after it moves from right to left and after that left to right. It working perfect but my question is how to make it as center after it move from left to right.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YpYbL/1/)

Comment: its better to provide a fiddle for this

Comment: What's your css for font-style onload before the animation starts?

Comment: @Rex I edited my ques with fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  jQuery('.font-style').animate({
  'right': '300px'
  },'slow').animate({
  'left': '300px'
  },'slow').animate({
  'left': '0',
  'right': '0'
  });


<div style="width:100%" id="p">
<div class="font-style" style=position:relative>Hi all How are you !!!</div>
</div>


#p{text-align:center;}
font-style{
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LRSbZ/

Answer (score 1):

Try this Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/Da8E4/), This is more helpful for you

Comment: where is the demo i didn't see any thing ?

Comment: +1 Thanks for providing the demo,but it continuously moving here and there. I am not sure is there is a way to stop after move from left to right and right to left alone